# How to list non existent items?

Tags: sql, mysql

the title might be a little bit confusing, let me explain, ;)
I have 3 tables:

```
[names]
n_id;name
1;Jeff
2;Adam

[books]
b_id;title
1;Book1
2;Book2

[read]
n_id;b_id
```

The table [**read**] is a table with read books.
if Adam reads "Book1" the item in [read] looks like this:

```
2;1
```

so far, so good.
Now, is there a way to know which books werent read by a person?
We know that only Adam read a book "Book1", so the query should output something like this:

```
n_id;name;b_id;title
1;Jeff;1;Book1
1;Jeff;2;Book2
2;Adam;2;Book2
```

is it possible to do this in 1 query or do I need some scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) to get all possible combinations of `names` and `books` and then use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) on `read` with `IS NULL` to remove rows that exist there.

The `LEFT JOIN` returns `NULL` for all joined columns where no rows exist, so checking if `r.n_id IS NULL` removes those rows where the join actually found rows in `read`.

```
SELECT n.n_id, n.name, b.b_id, b.title
FROM names n
CROSS JOIN books b
LEFT JOIN read r ON ( r.n_id = n.n_id AND r.b_id = b.b_id )
WHERE r.n_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a cross join to generate all pairs of `name` vs `book`, and then join with the `read` table and check where the join fails.

```
SELECT names.n_id, names.name, books.b_id, books.title
FROM names
CROSS JOIN books 
LEFT JOIN read
ON names.n_id = read.n_id AND books.b_id = read.b_id
WHERE read.n_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do a cartesian join between names and books to get all possible name/book combinations, then minus the ones that have been read:

```
SELECT n_id, b_id
FROM names, books
MINUS
SELECT n_id, b_id
FROM read
```

Others have suggested doing a cross join and a left join, which would also work perfectly well.  Might want to try both to see which is faster in a real-world scenario - I suspect the left join others suggested would be faster, but not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was, "Is there a way to know which books werent read by **a** person?"  But your sample query results showed the answer to the question, "Is there a way to know which books weren't read by all people?"

If you're really looking just to run the query for a specific person, something like this should work:

```
SELECT b_id, title
FROM books  --You said you're just looking for books
WHERE b_id NOT IN
  (SELECT b_id
   FROM read
   WHERE n_id = @names_id) --pass in the names_id as a parameter
```